# What determines the language splits installed with apps?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, apk, languages

I have an Android 10 device that I recently updated the (custom) ROM on, and now (for apps that have splits that include language splits - for example, `config.en.apk`) when installing or updating an app, I get not only English, but Spanish (`config.es.apk`), as well.

In System / Languages, I have only English (United States) selected. Installing the same apps on other devices installs English only (the aforementioned `config.en.apk`).

What setting or configuration option forces apps to add support for Spanish?

Comment: My device is set to German and I am in Germany and most split apps are installed with a German "de" split config and an "en". Just a few apps have only a "de" split installed. So I don't see a rule in when an app installs multiple language splits. May be there is a default language and if the local language split is incomplete (does not contain all messages in a translated version) the the default language is installed?

Comment: Wild guess, either the device model is related to that specific country, or some system variables (e.g. `build.prop`) might also be related.

Comment: @AndrewT. As I stated, this did not happen before a recent ROM upgrade, so I don't believe that the model (Xiaomi A3) has any relation to a country that wants to include Spanish language splits. I don't see anything in the `build.prop` that suggests Spanish (in fact, one line states `ro.product.locale=en-US`). I can post the entire `build.prop` (2668 characters), if desired.